# Find number of matches in two columns, where one of them is a dictionary

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to compare two columns and return total number of matches in **Google Sheets**.

**COLUMN A**
CAR
GIFT
RUN
DOG

**COLUMN B**
GIFT
GIFT
DOG
CAT

CAT
HUMAN
RUN
RUN
RUN

Comparing these two columns (where Column A is the dictionary) should return 6 (2 gifts, 1 dog, and 3 runs). It should be mentioned that blank cells should be ignored and should not count between the two columns. It should also be mentioned that column A is subject to change and more entries could be added at anytime (so I'd like to use A2:A range).

Comment: Could you please attach a copy of the Google Sheet?

Comment: @taylor.2317 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1afiDAdbrEbRR9XLmB0m1p7FZGh__env7BELHDBj6bXU/ I made a mockup sheet.

Comment: Do the keywords need to be on another sheet?

Comment: @taylor.2317 It does need to be on another sheet, yes.

Comment: Ok, my solution works with it on 2 separate sheets :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using a `count` and `match`

```
=arrayformula(count(match(B2:B, A2:A, 0)))
```

[image: output]

If in different sheet, just prepend the sheet name to the range

```
=arrayformula(count(match(Sheet2!A2:A, Sheet1!A2:A, 0)))
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 0):

Use this formula as it counts how many time each appears:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(COUNTIF(A2:A,Sheet1!A2:A)))
```

Comment: Solution seems to be very tedious and manual

Comment: It just sums up the 4 equations, e.g. 0 + 2 + 3 + 1 = 6

Comment: why not incorporate `arrayformula` and `sum`?

Comment: There are multiple ways of fixing this problem, including using `countif()`, `countifs()`, `arrayformula()`, `sum()`, `counta()`.

Comment: @NaziA updated, thanks